# Is [media] tag just misspelled [median]?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [media](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media) tag (11 questions), am I missing something, or is it just misspelled [median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/median)..?

EDIT: In obvious cases I started re-tagging the questions.

Comment: "*In obvious cases I started re-tagging the questions*" ... excellent.

Comment: The [media] tag has a wiki excerpt. It says `Questions related to statistics in the media`. It has a wiki too. It says `Apply this tag to questions specifically about the use of statistics within the popular media.` Both were written by whuber in 2011. So I think it's pretty obvious that it is not a misspelled "median".

Comment: (On the other hand, one might reasonably worry that it's too confusing name for a tag and we should rather get rid of it.)

Comment: @amoeba I don't know how I missed it... But I also think it's confusing and you can easily misspell "median" (seems it already happened few times).

Comment: Yes. I think we should either rename the tag (can be done manually by replacing it on all threads) or get rid of it altogether. It does not seem to be used a lot and I am not sure it's useful. If, however, people think it *is* useful, let's rename it into something less similar to [median]. Perhaps [mass-media]?

Comment: @amoeba the question is: do we need it at all?

Comment: @Tim Personally I think the tag brings together some threads in a useful manner. I think questions about statistical claims in the media are a distinct category of query - in particular I think it is likely that by reading a couple of other threads in that category, people may find the answer to their own problem (how to interpret a poll result or some other claim), which I think ultimately determines whether the tag is useful.

Comment: @Silverfish Any ideas then on the most appropriate tag name (something that is less likely to be confused with "median")?

Comment: @amoeba No brainwaves here. Best I have at the moment is `[statistics-in-media]` which is at least unambiguous but downside is not easily "discoverable". I don't think `[press]` works so well as it excludes broadcast media, and `[news]` sounds like it might include "news about statistics" or "new developments in statistics"

Comment: @Silverfish And `[mass-media]`?

Comment: @amoeba I think `[statistics-in-media]` is probably clearer in function. One thing about `[mass-media]` is that it sounds like it wouldn't include e.g. discussion of statistics in a popular blog which `[statistics-in-media]` might.

Comment: @Silverfish it always could be book-index style `[media-statistics-in]` but I don't know if it makes sense...

Comment: Tim, I have implemented @Silverfish'es suggestion (see update). You might want to accept his answer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[media](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media) when used correctly does group together a bunch of conceptually related questions, so seems useful. But it poses typo/autocompletion issues with [median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/median).

I propose a change of name to [statistics-in-media](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics-in-media), which would be less prone to confusion.

---

**Update (Sep 15)** by @amoeba: I have retagged all threads into `[statistics-in-media]`. I wrote the following tag excerpt for it:

> Questions related to statistics in the media (TV, radio, newspapers, blogs, etc.)

Comment: How many such typos have there been?

Comment: @gung Tim would know that. If he found several instances of misclassification in a tag with only ~10 members that is quite a large percentage.